# GWT how to add a custom cell to celltable/datagrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, cell, custom-cell, gwt-celltable

I have rendered a custom cell which combines an image and text.
It looks like this:

```
   class ImageTextCell extends AbstractCell<String>
```

My question is how to add this cell into celltable/datagrid.
I have tired this.

```
  Column<Message, String> iconColumn = new Column<Message, String>(new ImageTextCell())
            {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Message versionStatus) {

            return ? // I dont know what to type here. How to return the ImageTextCell object           }
    };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The role of the `Cell` object is to turn a value into a piece of HTML.  The role of the `Column` is to get that value from each row.  For example, you have a bunch of `Messages`, each one on its own row - the Column should take a `Message` and figure out what `String` to pass to the `Cell`.

The output of `getValue` will be fed into the input of `render`.  The output of `render` should be the HTML you want to see in your app.

Pseudo-codily, here's what GWT does for you:

```
for each Message in your table {
    pass the Message into Column.getValue and get out a String
    pass that String into Cell.render and get out some HTML
    add that HTML inside a <td> element in the table we're drawing
}
```

You just have to define Column.getValue and Cell.render so that this process makes the table you want.

Comment: I love this kind of explanation because I am a newb in GWT. It makes everything clear. thank you

Comment: If I pass imageResource + text as the return value of String type in Column.getValue() to Cell.render, how can I add a css.style to the image. More specifically, what I return in getValue() is "<image url(......) >  " +  " my text" , I pass this to render and successfully got what I want. But i want to add some css style on the image such as padding-right to make some space between image and text, and vertical-align to image so that the text can be in the middle of the <div>. But how can I do this

Comment: I know I can add style in render for both image+text. But I just want to add some css style for the image but not text. So what I can do is to add the style before I pass this to render() right? and How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

here is a way I do to display a png flag in my app:

> ```
>   Column<IStationMini, ImageResource> flag = new Column<IStationMini, ImageResource>( new ImageResourceCell()) {
>         @Override
>         public ImageResource getValue(IStationMini station) {
>             return FlagsTools.getFlag( station.getCountry());
>         }
>     };
> this.addColumn( flag ) ;
> ```

the "FlagsTools.getFlag()" returns an imageResource